# CreateView-Django y que reciba datos por defecto

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Se necesita crear un nuevo registro que está relacionado con otro por medio de un `ForeingKey`. Al usar la vista `BookInstanceCreate` (`CreateView`) guarda el nuevo registro sin inconveniente.

Dejo el código que tengo con los campos de interés, que se está usando para una biblioteca en donde un libro puede tener muchas copias:

Archivo `models.py`:

```
import uuid
class Book(models.Model):

    title=models.CharField(
        max_length=100, 
        help_text="enter the book's name"
    )
    summary=models.TextField(
        max_length=1000, 
        help_text="insert a short description"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class BookInstance(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True, 
        default=uuid.uuid4, 
        help_text="ID único para este libro particular en toda la biblioteca"
    )

    book = models.ForeignKey(
        'Book',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True
    )
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model= BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog,can_mark_returned'
    """success_url='/books_details/<int:pk>/'"""
```

---

Tengo dos problemas.

- Necesito regresar al detalle del libro, no al de la instancia del libro. AL usar `success_url='/books_details/<int:pk>/` que es a donde quiero retornar tengo que mi URL necesita una `pk`, pero no sé cómo pasársela.
- El formulario que genera class (`CreateView`) contiene todos los campos del modelo ¿cómo hacer para que en el campo llamado `book` del modelo `BookInstance` esté por defecto el valor del libro al que está instanciando y solo modificar los que me interesan añadiendo `fields =[...]` en `CrateView`? El llamado a esta vista basa en clases (`CreateView`) se puede efectuar cuando estamos viendo el detalle del los libros (el detalle del un libro - modelo `Book`)

No llevo mucho con Django, agradezco el esfuerzo por comprender mi duda, gracias.

---

**Actualización:**

Después de realizar las modificaciones aportadas por Julio Cesar, se logró solucionar la primera parte sin inconveniente. Para la segunda parte tengo el siguiente código:

Archivo `views.py`:

```
class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    paginate_by=10

class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model= BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog,can_mark_returned'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args = [self.object.book.id])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        book_id=self.kwars['book_id']
        form.instance.book = Book.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
path(
    route='books_details/<int:pk>', 
    view= views.BookDetailView.as_view(), 
    name='book-detail'
     ),
path(
    route='bookInstance/<int:pk>/', 
    view=views.BookInstanceCreate.as_view(),
    name='bookinstance-create'
    ),
```

Cuando voy a ingresar a el detalle de un libro y ver las copias disponibles

```
route='books_details/<int:pk>', view= views.BookDetailView.as_view(),
```

Al llamar a la correspondiente vista me está generando el siguiente error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /catalog/books_details/2 Reverse for 'bookinstance-create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/bookInstance/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

He tratado de modificar la vista `BookInstanceCreate` para pasarle el `pk` pero me dice que no ha sido definido y no he logrado pasarle el parámetro. Agradezco la colaboración.

Comment: Respecto al segundo problema no lo entiendo muy bien, de ser posible actualizar tu pregunta con mas detalles respecto al segundo problema para así ayudarte con mayor facilidad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para solucionar el primer problema, hay que enviarle como argumento el `id` de la instancia relacionada del modelo `Book` a la URL, sobrescribiendo el método [`get_success_url`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_success_url):

> ```
> class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
>     model= BookInstance
>     fields = '__all__'
>     template_name = '...'
>     permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
>
>     def get_success_url(self):
>         return reverse('book-detail', args = [self.object.book.id])
> ```
>
> **El atributo [`object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object):**
>
> Al usar `CreateView` tiene acceso a `self.object`, que es el objeto
>   que se está creando. Si el objeto aún no se ha creado, el valor será
>   `None`.

---

Para solucionar el segundo problema, necesitamos saber o identificar la instancia del modelo `Book`, una forma de hacerlo es que la URL que apunta a la vista `BookInstanceCreate` reciba como parámetro el `id` de este:

```
path('.../<int:pk>/', BookInstanceCreate.as_view(), name = '...')
```

Una ves hecho esto, hay que sobrescribir el método [`form_valid`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid) de la vista `CreateView`:

> ```
> class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
>     model= BookInstance
>     fields = [...] # <- los campos que necesites
>     template_name = '...'
>     permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'
>
>     def get_success_url(self):
>         return reverse('book-detail', args = [self.object.book.id])
>
>     def form_valid(self, form):
>         form.instance.book = Book.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
>
>         return super().form_valid(form)
> ```
>
> **El método [`form_valid`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid):**
>
> Dicho método se encarga de guardar el objeto en la db siempre y cuando
>   **el form sea valido.**

De esta manera no necesitas mostrar el campo `book`, pues por defecto sera una instancia especifica del modelo `Book`.

Eso seria todo, espero haberte ayudado.

---

**Actualización:**

Según el error no le estas pasando el `id` o `pk` a la URL, en tu plantilla, asegúrate de hacer lo siguiente, supongo que lo debes estar haciendo en la vista de detalle de `Book` (`BookDetailView`):

```
<a href="{% url 'bookinstance-create' object.pk %}">...</a>
```

De esta manera le pasas como argumento el `id` o `pk` a la URL.

Por otra parte, viendo el código de la vista `BookInstanceCreate`, en el método `form_valid` haces lo siguiente:

```
...
book_id=self.kwars['book_id']
...
```

Lo cual dará error, primero porque el atributo `kwars` no existe (es `kwargs`), y el segundo error (`KeyError`) porque la key `book_id` no existe, esto se puede ver en la URL que apunta a la vista, en ningún momento tiene un parámetro llamado `book_id` (no entiendo porque declaras dicha variable, pero no es necesaria).

Comment: Julio, muchas gracias por tu colaboración. La primera parte me funcionó de maravilla, en el segundo hice lo indicado, agregar un parámetro a la URL y sobreescribir def form_valid() y me genera un problema cuando accedo al detalle del libro (no al de la instancia de libro) y entiendo que no encuentra cómo pasar el parámetro a la url, "NoReverseMatch at /catalog/books_details/2
Reverse for 'bookinstance-create' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['catalog/bookInstance/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']". Estoy tratando de sobreescribir def form:valid() sin llegar a un resultado,

Comment: En que parte te da error (en que vista, en un `ListView`?, etc)? te aseguraste de pasarle a la vista `BookInstanceCreate` el id? de ser posible actualiza tu pregunta con los detalles.

Comment: En  '''class BookDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book '''  y esto es lo que tengo en la otra vista ;     ""class 
 BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model= BookInstance
    fields = '__all__'
    permission_required = 'catalog,can_mark_returned'
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args = [self.object.book.id])
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        book_id=self.kwars['book_id']
        form.instance.book = Book.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

        return super().form_valid(form)

Comment: @jrco1989 mejor actualiza tu pregunta con el código y relatando tu nuevo inconveniente con detalles, así sera mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Si modifico class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView): para agregarle otro parámetro como por ejemplo class BookInstanceCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin,pk, CreateView): me genera error por que pk no estaría definido.

Comment: vale, voy a actualizar

Comment: @jrco1989 ya actualice mi respuesta con la solución, échale un vistaso y dime si funciona.

Comment: Julio, efectivamente la solución que das funcionó correctamente, le agradezco la claridad que tuvo en la explicación, muy buena, me aclaró bastantes cosas que no entendía. Me faltaba pasar el parámetro desde el template y  lo de 'book_id=self.kwars['book_id']' lo hice porque estaba probando ora solución y se me fue cuando pegué la tuya.  Muy amable por el tiempo, en verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)